# Медиавложение в личных сообщениях ВКонтанте

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Для создания бота мне бы хотелось осуществить отправку фото и других медиавложений от лица сообщества в личные сообщения.
Прошу скинуть пример и объяснение. 
Буду крайне признателен. 
Пишу на python 3.7

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/messages тут все очень подробно изложено

Comment: А можно на примере показать? а то плохо понимаю

Answer (score 0):

```python
import json

peer_id = ......
photo = open('test.jpg', 'rb')
pfile = api.photos.getMessagesUploadServer(peer_id = peer_id, files = {'photo': photo}, v = "5.38")
pf = post(pfile['upload_url'], files = {'photo': photo}).json()
photo = api.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(server = pf['server'], photo = pf['photo'], hash = pf['hash'], v = "5.38")[0]
attachment = 'photo{}_{}'.format(peer_id, photo[0]['id'])
```

Как вы и хотели, пример кода.

Примечание: в `peer_id` надо вводить свой id (лично я не знаю, почему id сообщества не работает). А переменную `attachment` уже надо положить при отправлении сообщения.

```pytnon
api.messages.send(peer_id = ..., attachment = attachment, random_id = 0, v = '5.92')
```

Библиотека vk